# Suppose a book with 100 pages is divided into 5 chapters of 20 pages each. The book contains 10 typos distributed randomly amongst the pages.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

(a) What is the probability that Page# 89 has exactly 2 typos?

I know this is a poison distribution question, and the rate happens to be 0.1 typos/page, but I'm having trouble on how I would figure out specifically the probability for page 89 having 2 typos.

Comment: Why is this Poisson? Even the chapter information looks like a red herring. You have ten objects placed randomly in one hundred buckets. What is the probability that bucket $89$ has two of the objects?

Comment: You can approximate the distribution with a Poisson if you want, just use a mean of $.1$ as you suggest.  But why approximate?  Just use the binomial.

Comment: You can think about this as sampling with replacement. "Suppose I have a hundred numbered balls in a fish bowl. If I take out ten of them with replacement, whats the probability that I take out the same ball exactly twice?" I'm not sure if that helps you understand the problem, but it does for me.

Answer (score 1):

What's the probability that the first and second error both occur on page #89? Assuming no correlation, it's $(0.01)^2 = 0.0001$.

What's the probability that any two specific errors occurs on page #89? It's $0.0001$.

Assuming that exactly two of the ten errors occurs on page #89, how many different ways could this occur? That's ${}_{10}C_{2} = 45$.

So, the probability is:
$$
P = (45)(0.0001) = 0.0045
$$

Comment: I'm tired, so maybe I'm overlooking something, but this is what I was thinking of when I commented on your question.